# How Do I Solve This Two Notes From R Package Auto-check?

Tags: r

I submitted a `new package` to `CRAN`which was auto-checked with the following message:

`checking for detritus in the temp directory ... NOTE Found the following files/directories: 'Rscript2d8b02f225c29' 'Rscripte6ac2f225c29'` gives me a great concern.

**WHAT I WANT**

How do I make my check to be free of this auto-check error?

> - using log directory 'd:/RCompile/CRANincoming/R-devel/OBL.Rcheck'
> - using R Under development (unstable) (2022-06-18 r82503 ucrt)
> - using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
> - using session charset: UTF-8
> - checking for file 'OBL/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
> - checking extension type ... Package
> - this is package 'OBL' version '0.1.0'
> - package encoding: UTF-8
> - checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
>   Maintainer: 'Daniel James futathesis@gmail.com'

> New submission
>
> - checking package namespace information ... OK
> - checking package dependencies ... OK
> - checking if this is a source package ... OK
> - checking if there is a namespace ... OK
> - checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
> - checking for portable file names ... OK
> - checking whether package 'OBL' can be installed ... OK
> - checking installed package size ... OK
> - checking package directory ... OK
> - checking for future file timestamps ... OK
> - checking 'build' directory ... OK
> - checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
> - checking top-level files ... OK
> - checking for left-over files ... OK
> - checking index information ... OK
> - checking package subdirectories ... OK
> - checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
> - checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
> - checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
> - checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
> - checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
> - checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
> - checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
> - checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
> - checking use of S3 registration ... OK
> - checking dependencies in R code ... OK
> - checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
> - checking replacement functions ... OK
> - checking foreign function calls ... OK
> - checking R code for possible problems ... [13s] OK
> - checking Rd files ... [0s] OK
> - checking Rd metadata ... OK
> - checking Rd line widths ... OK
> - checking Rd cross-references ... OK
> - checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
> - checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
> - checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
> - checking Rd contents ... OK
> - checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
> - checking contents of 'data' directory ... OK
> - checking data for non-ASCII characters ... OK
> - checking LazyData ... OK
> - checking data for ASCII and uncompressed saves ... OK
> - checking R/sysdata.rda ... OK
> - checking installed files from 'inst/doc' ... OK
> - checking files in 'vignettes' ... OK
> - checking examples ... NONE
> - checking for unstated dependencies in vignettes ... OK
> - checking package vignettes in 'inst/doc' ... OK
> - checking re-building of vignette outputs ... [27s] OK
> - checking PDF version of manual ... OK
> - checking for detritus in the temp directory ... NOTE
>   Found the following files/directories:
>   'Rscript2d8b02f225c29' 'Rscripte6ac2f225c29'
> - DONE
>   Status: 2 NOTEs

Comment: Please do not write to _both_ the r-package-devel list _and_ StackOverflow. Pick one.  Also, without your code, nobody can tell.  _Something_ in the process of assembling or checking the package writes a temporary file where it should not -- and R tells you about it.  Now you as author should make it write to a proper temporary location (rather than the current build directory) and/or not make it write at all.

Comment: Also, the other NOTE is on this being a new package not on CRAN is unavoidable.  So you are fighting one, not two, of them.

Comment: My guest for a viable solution is pushing me around. I beg I need a solution, and I need my hand laid on it.  I am not knowledgeable in building software. What one thing or set of procedures to follow to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `R CMD check` NOTE:

```
checking for detritus in the temp directory ... NOTE
Found the following files/directories: 'Rscript2d8b02f225c29' 'Rscripte6ac2f225c29'
```

is because there were two parallel workers launched in a package test or a package vignette, but never stopped (e.g. by `parallel::stopCluster(...)`.  This NOTE happens only on MS Windows and with R (>= 4.3.0).

Although it's not specific to **parallelly**, you can read more about it in Section 'For package developers' of [`help("makeClusterPSOCK", package = "parallelly")`](https://parallelly.futureverse.org/reference/makeClusterPSOCK.html).

Comment: may be worth including the link to the `r-package-devel` discussion thread as well? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2022q3/008526.html